# compare list values withina python dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I think it is very basic, but I struggle to find a way to solve this.
In a python dictionary like below (where values are lists), how can I conveniently compare values of each key-value pair?
For example, how can I retrieve the key-value pairs where:

1. Elements of values are not repeated in values of other key-value pairs,
2. If the first element of the value present in other values, select the pair where the second element of the value in larger.

In other words, I need to get

```
"a": ["bc", "5", "0"]
"b": ["nc", "8", "5"]
```

```
test_dict = {"a": ["bc", "5", "0"], "b": ["nc", "8", "5"], "c": ["bc", "3", "0"]}
```

Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: what should be output for `test_dict`?

Comment: please see the update post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use an auxilliary mapping indexed by first element of the value:

```
aux = {}
for k, v in test_dict.items():
    if v[0] in aux:
        if v[1] > aux[v[0]][1][1]:
            aux[v[0]] = (k, v)
    else: aux[v[0]] = (k, v)
resul = {k: v for k,v in aux.values()}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a comprehension, unpacking all the elements to keep things clean.  Try

```
In [1]: out = {k:(v1, v2, v3) for k, (v1, v2, v3) in test_dict.items() if k not in v1 and int(v2) > int(v3)}

In [2]: out
Out[2]: {'a': ('bc', '5', '0'), 'b': ('nc', '8', '5')}
```

Answer (score 1):

Made it into one-liner. It looks for the third element for the comparison too (not just the second).

It creates a *dict* twice. First with the first element as a key and then uses its values to generate the result.

```
dict({v[0]:(k,v) for v,k in sorted((v,k) for k,v in test_dict.items())}.values())
```